# Calculating trend for 3 dimensional data

Tags: regression, logistic

Forgive me for a potential dupe, as I don't know the correct terminology for searching for an existing question. Also please add tag "trends" or similar, as I don't have the reputation to create new tags.

I have market data like so:

```
X  Y  S
10 20 0
20 30 1
20 25 0
15 10 0
...
```

Where X and Y are certain variables used to calculate a quote to a customer, and S is whether the customer took the offer (0 = no, 1 = yes).

I would now like to calculate some kind of a 2-dimensional trend for X, Y and S, and to produce a function f(X, Y) = s, where s is the probability (0..1) of the customer accepting the offer for given X and Y. We can assume the "trend" is a plane, and not some funky 3D surface.

So:

1. How do I determine f and
2. if it's not something easily done in Excel, what is the proper temrinology to look for when searching for a programming language library for this purpose?

Comment: What you want is a logistic regression. Cross Validated is the better stack overflow forum for this

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach would be to form a logistic regression expression. The log-odds of S=1 is modeled as a regression function of X and Y. Since Excel is pretty much never the right answer for anything, you should pick different modeling software, R being a free, complete, and accurate alternative to Excel.

```
 reg.mdl <- glm( S ~ X + Y, data=dfrm, family="binomial")
```

(It appears that Excel errors are at the bottom of a recent academic controversy: http://www.nextnewdeal.net/rortybomb/researchers-finally-replicated-reinhart-rogoff-and-there-are-serious-problems )

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, you are probably right about Excel and R. I'm new to R, so could you make the example complete by showing what format should the data (S, X and Y) be provided so that the statement above would really run? I'll accept the answer then.